# Grub hangs if 4G USB Wifi Dongle is connected

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, grub2, usb-modem

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 + Windows XP dual boot and everything works fine except my Airtel 4G LTE Wifi USB broadband modem / dongle.

Right now, here's the STUPID way in which I'm getting the USB dongle to work:

1. Disconnect the USB dongle from the USB port (grub hangs otherwise)
2. Boot into Windows XP
3. Connect the USB dongle. Windows detects it and everything works.
4. Restart the machine via XP (this ensures that the dongle doesn't poweroff. It's important)
5. Now boot into Ubuntu
6. Ubuntu detects the dongle and it appears as eth0 or eth1 (depending on the day of the month :-) and everything works.

I want to avoid this ritual and leave the dongle always connected to the USB port. I don't want grub to hang, I don't want to boot into Windows to get the dongle to work.

Can someone on this forum help me fix this? I've searched the entire World Wide Web for this, but I couldn't find out what to do.

PLEASE!

**Update:** I just found out from Airtel Customer Support that they don't support 64-bit OSes (my Ubuntu is). Out of curiosity, I asked the lady what I'd need to do if it were 32-bit. She said go to 192.168.1.1, login and click connect:-) I was like - if only it were that simple...!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for others struggling with this...

The issue is grub seeing the USB modem as a second hard drive (/dev/sdb as reported by bootinfoscript) for a few seconds before the modem mode-switches to its final state. Looks like grub thinks someone physically pulled out a hard disk while it was running... or something. And therefore, it hangs.

To solve the problem, you've got to make sure grub doesn't see any "mode-switching" USB device - in this case the Airtel 4G Wifi LTE broadband modem dongle. The dongle should "boot up" completely before grub takes over.

All I did was to ensure we spend 30 seconds seeing the BIOS splash screen before letting grub takeover. In that time the USB devices mode-switches to its final state (in the unlikely situation that it doesn't, we're back to square one).

How to do it? Enter BIOS setup and set up Hard Disk Pre-Delay of 30 sec. That's it.

With this change, I can leave the dongle always connected to the USB port. I don't have go get into Windows if I don't want to.

The flip side of this workaround is that boot is 30 seconds longer. I don't mind it.